# Is it ok to assign uninitialized char pointer or char pointer in struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char

```c
struct Test {
    char *s;
};

Test test;
test.s = "Hey";
```

or

```c
char *s;

s = "Hey";
```

So I don't need the string to be edited, or anything like that. I was just wondering if the code above me is allowed, or is safe to use?

And if this should not be used, why?

Or, if there is a better way I should do this?

Comment: In C all literal strings are null-terminated arrays of (read only) characters. The life-time of those arrays is the same as the life-time of the full program. Your assignment makes the pointer point to the first character in the array. The read only bit is why it's recommended to use `const char *` for such variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is allowed. You won't even get a warning from `-Wall` or `-Wextra`, though you will with `-Wwrite-strings`.

It is safe as long as you don't change any of the elements of the array to which `s` points (e.g. `*s` or `s[0]`) or try to free `s`.

You'll probably run into problems if you deal with a bunch of `Test` and some strings are read-only and some aren't. For example, how would you know if a string should be freed when the `Test` is destroyed?

If none of your strings will be edited or freed, you could use the following to get at least a warning if you try to do something you shouldn't:

```c
struct Test {
    const char *s;
};
```

In the other direction, you could make a copy of the string that can be edited and/or freed.

```c
test.s = strdup("Hey");
```

Comment: "For example, how would you know if a string should be freed when the Test is destroyed?" So, are you basically saying that I'd have to figure out which string to free before freeing the struct if malloc?

Comment: Yeah. Or when it goes out of scope if you have `Test test;` Cause `test.s="Hey"; free(test.s);` is bad, and not calling `free(test.s)` could be a memory leak in other circumstances. If you always deal with one or the other, then there's no problem. But if you have a mix, you might have problems.

Comment: Is also for example, `char buff[] = "Hey";` `char *s = buff;` also fine, or I should do strdup? (But, I don't use strdup)

Comment: This version can be written to, but not freed. It really depends on what you need. A question you should often ask yourself is "Who *owns* this?" The owner is the code or data structure responsible for keep the var/array allocated as long it's still be used, and conversely, it's also responsible for freeing the var/array when it's no longer used. (Ownership can be transferred.) If `test` is the owner, `strdup` will need to be used (or you'll need a flag that indicates whether it should be freed or not). Otherwise, either of the other ones could be acceptable.

Comment: You might get a warning depending on compiler settings (some people like to enable warning for using non-const `char *` to point to string literals)

Comment: @M.M, It's not enabled by `-Wall` or `-Wextra`, and I've clarified the answer on that point. If you know the name of the warning, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @ikegami `-Wwrite-strings`